# C# Crear Mock Configuration.GetSection(“Section:SubSection”) a partir de una lista de objetos

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias

### Objetivo

Crear un objeto mock, usando Moq and XUnit, para cargar la sección "Character/Skills" y así aumentar la cobertura de las pruebas unitarias.

The SUT (en algún punto), lee y carga las configuraciones de la siguiente manera:

```
var skills = Configuration.GetSection(“Character:Skills”);
```

Del siguiente appSetting:

```
{
    "dummyConfig1": {
        "Description": "bla bla bla...",
    },
    "Character": {
    "Name": "John Wick",
    "Description": "A retired hitman seeking vengeance for the killing of the dog given to him...",
    "Skills": [
        {
        "Key": "CQC Combat",
        "Id": "15465"
        },
        {
        "Key": "Firearms",
        "Id": "14321"
        },
        {
        "Key": "Stealth",
        "Id": "09674"
        },
        {
        "Key": "Speed",
        "Id": "10203"
        }
    ],
    "DummyConf2": "more bla bla bla..."
}
```

### Lectura previa

Leyendo estos post (y otros en inglés, como resultado de una búsqueda en Google), noté que para la preparación de los "mocks", usan únicamente tipos de datos "string" o en su defecto, un  objeto *new Mock<IConfigurationSection>* (sin configuraciones):

- [Stack Overflow - how to mock Configuration.GetSection(“foo:bar”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201588/c-sharp-how-to-mock-configuration-getsectionfoobar-getliststring),
- [Mocking IConfiguration extension method](https://www.pmichaels.net/2019/05/04/mocking-iconfiguration-extension-method/)
- [Mocking IConfiguration Getvalue() extension method in Unit Test](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/november/mocking-iconfiguration-getvalue-extension-methods-in-unit-test/)

**Restricción:** Copiando el archivo "appSetting" dentro del proyecto de Testing (o creando un MemoryStream) para cargar las configuraciones reales podría resolver este escenario, pero ahí sería una prueba "de integración", en vez de "unitarias"; ya que habría dependencias de operaciones de E/S.

### Abordaje

La ideal del código (más adelante) está "mocando" cada una de las propiedades (key/id) para después armar   un árbol parecido a este:

- "Character" ------ Configuración a ser leída, usando `GetSection()` y luego `Get<T>()`

  - "Skills" ------ Lista de configuración con los atributos

    - "Key" - "CQC Combat"   ------ Valores primitivos 1
    - "Id"  - "15465"        ------ Valores primitivos 2

### El código

```
var skillsConfiguration = new List<SkillsConfig>
{
    new SkillsConfig { Key = "CQC Combat"   , Id = "15465" },
    new SkillsConfig { Key = "Firearms"     , Id = "14321" },
    new SkillsConfig { Key = "Stealh"       , Id = "09674" },
    new SkillsConfig { Key = "Speed"        , Id = "10203" },
};

var configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
var mockConfSections = new List<IConfigurationSection>();

foreach (var skill in skillsConfiguration)
{
    var index = skillsConfiguration.IndexOf(skill);

    //Set the Key string value
    var mockConfSectionKey = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
    mockConfSectionKey.Setup(s => s.Path).Returns($"Character:Skills:{index}:Key");
    mockConfSectionKey.Setup(s => s.Key).Returns("Key");
    mockConfSectionKey.Setup(s => s.Value).Returns(skill.Key);

    //Set the Id string value
    var mockConfSectionId = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
    mockConfSectionId.Setup(s => s.Path).Returns($"Character:Skills:{index}:Id");
    mockConfSectionId.Setup(s => s.Key).Returns("Id");
    mockConfSectionId.Setup(s => s.Value).Returns(skill.Id);

    //Merge the attribute "key/id" as Configuration section list
    var mockConfSection = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();                
    mockConfSection.Setup(s => s.Path).Returns($"Character:Skills:{index}");
    mockConfSection.Setup(s => s.Key).Returns(index.ToString());
    mockConfSection.Setup(s => s.GetChildren()).Returns(new List<IConfigurationSection> { mockConfSectionKey.Object, mockConfSectionId.Object });    
    
    //Add the skill object with merged attributes
    mockConfSections.Add(mockConfSection.Object);
}

// Add the Skill's list
var skillsMockSections = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
skillsMockSections.Setup(cfg => cfg.Path).Returns("Character:Skills");
skillsMockSections.Setup(cfg => cfg.Key).Returns("Skills");
skillsMockSections.Setup(cfg => cfg.GetChildren()).Returns(mockConfSections);

//Mock the whole section, for using GetSection() method withing SUT
configurationMock.Setup(cfg => cfg.GetSection("Character:Skills")).Returns(skillsMockSections.Object);
```

### Resultados esperados

Ejecutando el sistema original, obtengo la lista instanciada con sus respectivos valores. Aquí la imagen:

[image: appsetting loaded sucessfully]

### Resultados mocados

El código arriba, obtengo la lista instanciada pero los valores de los atributos vienen nulos. Aquí la imagen:

[image: appsetting mocked with null values]

Answer (score 0):

Al final terminé refactorizando el código, eliminando todo el bloque de código `foreach` y reemplazando la incialización de la lista `var mockConfSections = new List<IConfigurationSection>();` por el siguiente código, el cual es más simple y limpio.

```cs
var fakeSkillSettings = projectRoles.SelectMany(
    skill => new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { $"Character:Skills:{skillsConfiguration.IndexOf(skill)}:Key", skill.Key },
        { $"Character:Skills:{skillsConfiguration.IndexOf(skill)}:Id" , skill.Id  },
});

var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
var mockConfSections = configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(fakeSkillSettings)
    .Build()
    .GetSection("Character:Skills")
    .GetChildren();
```

### Explicación

En la implementación anterior construí un árbol de configuraciones con nodos mocados, lo cual me llevó a la necesidad de construir un "Setup" para así retornar cada nodo, resultando en una solución bastante "inchada".

Basado en este artículo [Manteniendo la configuración en memoria (en inglés - Keeping Configuration Settings in Memory)](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/03/keeping-configuration-settings.aspx), proyecté cada elemento en un *Dictionary* plano, de la forma Key/Id usando [LINQ SelectMany](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany), luego monté la configuración en memoria y finalmente moqué la configuración con "nodos reales", resultando en un "mock setup".